# Differential Amplifier Exam Problem

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, amplifier, analog, differential

[image]

I am lost with how to approach part C and D of the question. In fact, I need some intuition with how to tune a differential amplifier.

Comment: This looks like home work how have you answered a and b? Where are you getting stuck?  We can help but we don't do your homework for you.

Comment: Read thru a math derivation of the DC transfer function of the FET diffpair. Then re-visit the question.

Comment: I did a, b and e, but stuck on c and d. Can you please send me some readings; I don't want you to do the problem for me, I want to know how to approach it.